# Is Using #ifdef a correct strategy

Tags: c++, linux, build, operating-system

So,I have a requirement that to do a particular task (say multithreading) that is totally os dependent (or like win32/linux api call).

Now i read somewhere, that using #ifdef we can actually write os dependent code

```
#ifdef __linux__
/*some linux codes*/
#endif
```

Now my question is....

Is it the right way to write my code(i.e using ifdef) and then releasing a single .cpp file for both windows and linux? Or should i break my code into two parts and release two different builds- one for linux and one for windows?

**Edit:**

Seems like question is way too broad, and that generates a lot of opinions.

Differentiate between the two approaches that i mentioned on the basis of Performance, build size etc(any other factor that i may have missed).

```
Class A {
.
.// Some variables and methods
.
};

class B: public A {

    void DoSomething() {
    // COntains linux codes and some windows code
    }
};
```

If suppose I don't use `#ifdef`, how am i going to write `dosomething()` method that calls right piece of code at right time

Comment: Using `#ifdef` is the usual way I have seen.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "right", doesn't it? One has a cleaner separation between the two builds, which is always good, while the other is more compact. Which one's more important?

Comment: Rule of thumb: for small differences (a few lines) inline #ifdefs are fine - for large differences (totally different implementations of functions etc) it's better to break stuff out into separate platform-specific files.

Comment: Another plus for ifdef is to avoid redundancy. @Ayush choubey: Do you want to release source or builds in the first place? Don´t mix this up.

Comment: You will still need to deploy two versions, one for windows and one for linux, as ifndef is interpreted in the precompiler. Most likely there is allready a cross-platform library that does what you need (threading and sockets - thats boost)

Comment: May be not the best strategy for big code bases, but at least still valid.

Comment: @PaulR It's not just a question of the number of lines.  It's where they are; if you start mixing `#ifdef` and `if (...) {` in the middle of a function, you'll never be able to maintain it.  And of course, the `#ifdef` solution becomes more and more unreadable the more variants you have to support.

Answer (score 1):

Solution #1: Use existing, debugged, documented library (e.g. boost) to hide the platform differences.  It uses lots of #ifdef's internally, but you don't have to worry about that.

Solution #2: Write your own platform independent library (see solution #1 for a better approach) and hide all the #ifdef's inside.

Solution #3: Do it in macros (ugh, but see ACE (although most of ACE is in a library, too.)

Solution #4: Use #ifdefs throughout your code whenever a platform difference arises.

Solution #4 is suitable for very-small, throw-away code programs.
Solution #3 is suitable if you are programming in the 1990's.
Solution #2 is suitable only if you can't use a real library for non-technical reasons.

Conclusion: Use Solution #1.

Comment: Another option is to define a standard interface and link with platform specific units.  Let the linker decide which platform specific modules to use.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  Agreed, but that is not as easy/useful as it appears at first glance.  It would require that the various platforms share a common ABI which they don't usually.  You can't take a Windows .obj file and link it to a linux .o file   Thus it's easier to compile and link for each desired target.  And now we're back to boost.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use `#ifdef` for this, but it quickly leads to
unmaintainable code.  A better solution is to abstract the
functionality into a class, and provide two different
implementations (two different source files) for that class.
(Even back in the days of C, we'd define a set of functions in
a header, and provide different source files for their
implementation.)

I generally put give the source files the same name, but put
them in platform dependent directories, e.g.: `thread.hh`, with
the sources in `Posix/thread.cc` and `Windows/thread.cc`.
Alternatively, you can put the implementations in files with
different names: `posix_thread.cc` and `windows_thread.cc`.

If you need dependencies in a header, the directory approach
also works.  Or you can use something like:

```
#include systemDependentHeader(thread.hh)
```

, where `systemDependentHeader` is a macro which does some token
pasting (with a token defined on the command line) and
stringizing.

Of course, in the case of threading, C++11 offers a standard
solution, which is what you should use; if you can't,
`boost::thread` isn't too far from the standard (I think).  More
generally, if you can find the work already done, you should
take advantage of it.  (But verify the quality of the library
first.  In the past, we had to back out of using ACE because it
was so buggy.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to develop your code for different platform you have to consider the following:

You can use `#ifdef or #if defined(x)` but you have to confine it only inside a header file, better if this file is called "platform.h". Inside your source code you can use the macros defined inside paltform.h file. So your business logic is same for both platform.

Let me provide you an example:

```
PLATFORM.H
// A platform depended print function inside platform.h file
#if defined( _EMBEDDED_OS_ )
  #include <embedded_os.h>
  #define print_msg(message) put_uart_bytes(message)
#elif defined( _WINDOWS_ )
  #include <windows.h>
  #define print_msg(message) printf(message)
#else
  #error undefined_platform
#endif



SOURCE.CPP
void main()
{
   print_msg("Ciao Mondo!");
}
```

As you see your source is same for each platform and your business logic is not dirty by several #ifdef directives

Comment: IMHO, rather messy.  Define a standard interface and let the linker decide which platform specific module to implement the interface.